# Can I print an image from a separate content type in my page--front.tpl.php?

Tags: theming, entities, media

This is a question in reference to Drupal 7, using the Zurb Foundation base theme framework. I've created a specific content type that only has an image field in it for purposes of making the image itself content manageable by the user so they can add/remove as they'd like.

I thought that I could access that image with the following code in my page--front.tpl.php file per my Googling of the subject, however, I'm getting no output at all.

```
<?php print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_my_image_field', array('label'=>'hidden'))); 
  ?>
```

I've also attempted several different variations of this to no avail.

How can I access and `print` out the contents of that field from that content type into my custom page template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what was ultimately the solution in our case in the event that anyone else runs in to this same problem again in the future.

Ultimately, the solution was to load the image from the node directly. Many thanks to my man Mike for helping get to the bottom of this.

```
<?php 
      $type = "homepage_hero_background"; // content type machine name
      $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));
      foreach ($nodes as $bg) {
        $uri = $bg->field_chp_background_image['und'][0]["uri"]; // field machine name
        $main_image = file_create_url( $uri );
      }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a view inside your front page template, insert this code in propper region. You'll need an image view

```
// Get the embeded view and render it.
drupal_render(views_embed_view('VIEW_NAME', 'DISPLAY_ID'));
```

replace VIEW-NAME and DISPLAY_ID with your data, you can find those values in last column on your image view

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display any custom field from specific content type , you can refer below code : please change your content type name in $type variable in below code here my content type name is "portfolio" , you will get all fields value from that particular content type.

```
$type = "portfolio";
//$test = array();
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));
foreach($nodes as $products){
 print_r($products); 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What does the $products variable represent? I'm assuming that this has something to do with your image field, but I'm not following you here - it's not clear.

Comment: Hello, here $products variable you can give any name , try to print that variable , you can give any variable name there like $test then it should look like  foreach($nodes as $test){  print_r($test); }  , try this code you will surly get your field , you will get your custom image field uri then you need to convert it in url using drupal's function like file_create_url , for example , $main_image = file_create_url($test->yourcustomimagefieldname['und'][0]['uri']); , so this function will create image url

Comment: This returns an error:

Error messageNotice: Undefined index: u‌​ri in include() (line 11 of sites/all/themes/my_theme/templates/page--front.tpl.php).

Comment: try to do  foreach($nodes as $test){ print_r($test); } and check if you are getting image field or not ?

Comment: check in admin that your field has image uploaded or not,if there will be no image then on doing print_r you will not get anything for that field. in my project i have field like this http://prntscr.com/flfhxz , so when i will run my code it will do print_r like image this http://prntscr.com/flfijd because in admin my field has value . please share your print_r screenshot , because above mention code works perfect for me.

Comment: Here's the whole thing and I can't get it to work:

<?php $type = "chp_bg";
          $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));
          foreach($nodes as $bg){
          print_r($bg);  
          }
          $main_image = file_create_url($bg-> field_chp_background_image['und'][0]['u‌​ri']); 
      ?>

Comment: btw- I *do* have an image in the field.

Comment: Hi, you have added $main_image outside loop please add it inside loop , try this code `<?php $type = "chp_bg"; 
      $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type)); 
      foreach($nodes as $bg){ 
          print_r($bg); 
          $main_image = file_create_url($bg->field_chp_background_image['und'][0]['uri']);
      }?>`

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work.